# Sharepoint: Automatically assigning a date/month to a List entry

Tags: sharepoint

I have a List that stores Monthly highlights but they aren't put into the List until the following month. The users would like it to automatically assign the previous month to each List item so for example if they put the highlights into the database in June, they want each item to say May because they are the monthly highlights for May. I know they could just make each item say May, manually, but they would like it to be automatic.

Thanks in advance for any responses!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly then the list item is created in, say June, but you want the column to show previous month i.e. May.

In that case you can create a calculated column in your list with following formula:

```
TEXT(DATE(YEAR([Created]),MONTH([Created])-1,DAY([Created])),"mmmm")
```

Comment: Thanks! this works if i make a new item in the list. There is a problem in that i alrwady had some data in the list so how can i get the older items to display the correct month?

Comment: @JoePatterson: The above formula should work for existing list items as it based on `[Created]` of list items.

Comment: Any idea why 2 of the columns are returning the month of November? The rest seem to be alright but 2 of them say November and this database didnt even exist then